# Playwright tests failing in CI with Failed to load Chrome DLL

Tags: playwright

EDIT: Downgrading @playwright/test to 1.27 has resolved this but it's less than ideal as a solution. I intend to raise it with playwright as an issue.

I'm looking for some help please with fixing an issue with our Playwright tests running in our Azure DevOps CI release. It intermittently fails with 'Failed to load chrome.dll'.

I've tried lots of various things so far to improve predictability around loading the browser but no luck so far. Here is what I've tried so far:

1. Installing & loading the browser from a specific file path - it installed\loaded from specified file path but still gave the error.
2. Skipping playwright browser install - no apparent change & it still gave error
3. Updated devops tasks prior to install & run test tasks to adhere to playwright docs - no change, still errored
4. Analysed test code for issues - discovered oddity in global_teardown\global_setup but attempt to fix (moved browser close from setup to teardown) didn't resolve
5. Setting install & load playwright browser path & only installing\loading chromium browser, then running tests in chromium - expected to see the browser load consistently but it still errored

I have noticed that when installing the playwright browser with various different commands, it sometimes doesn't show the progress bar while it's downloading. Could this be part of the issue? Example command below..

`set PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=%USERPROFILE%\file-path\&&npx playwright install --with-deps chromium`

It happens on multiple different build machines which makes me think it could be more a code thing than a build box issue but I haven't been able to rule out the box entirely as I don't have access to it.

Any tips to resolve this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!